# Parse JSON property name beginning with a numeric character in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

How can I parse the JSON property '1CustomSensor' in an Azure Stream Analytics Query?

```
{
"DeviceId" : "12345",
"Location" :
{
    "Lat": 47,
    "Long": 122
},
"SensorReadings" :
{
    "Temperature" : 80,
    "Humidity" : 70,
    "1CustomSensor" : 5,
    "2CustomSensor" : 99,
    "SensorMetadata" : 
    {
    "Manufacturer":"ABC",
    "Version":"1.2.45"
    }
}
```

}

```
SELECT
    DeviceID,
    Location.Lat,
    Location.Long,
    SensorReadings.1CustomSensor,
    SensorReadings.Temperature,
    SensorReadings.SensorMetadata.Version
FROM input
```

Using this query it objects to the property beginning with a number. The JSON I am receiving has the number in the name and I cannot change this.